# Get JSX Element from a Typescript Object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

My `typescript object` `state.ts` is like below

```
import { IconCalendarEvent, TablerIcon, IconRun } from "@tabler/icons";

export const StateIcon  = {    
  Validated: IconCalendarEvent,
  Running: IconRun
};
```

Basically this infers to

```
const StateIcon: {
    Validated: TablerIcon;
    Running: TablerIcon;
}
```

Now in my `React Component` , I want to return `JSX Element` based on a state

So I have written a function

```
const getIcon = (state: string) => {
  const r = (_.keys(StateIcon) as (keyof typeof StateIcon)[]).find((k) => {
    return k === state;
  });

  return <StateIcon[r] /> 
  
};
```

But this doesn't work saying `JSX element type 'StateIcon' does not have any construct or call signatures`

If I try below hard-coded it works fine.

```
return <StateIcon.Running />
```

I tried changing signature to

```
const getIcon = (state: string) => {
  const Icon = StateIcon[state];
  return <Icon />;
};
```

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type '{ Validated: TablerIcon;
> Running: TablerIcon; }'.   No index signature with a parameter of type
> 'string' was found on type '{ Validated: TablerIcon; Running:
> TablerIcon; }'

What I am missing here

Comment: Hmm. Try placing it in an intermediate variable (`const RunningIcon = StateIcon[r] ; return <RunningIcon />`), or try `<(StateIcon[R]) />`, maybe? I think it's just the syntax of indexing on an object and immediately using it as a JSX tag. You'll probably want to rename `StateIcon` to `stateIcons` though, since it's not a component, and being capitalized implies it is.

Comment: Maybe `<` has higher precedence than indexing?

Comment: `const Icon= StateIcon[state]` then `<Icon />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a "dynamic" component:

```
const getIcon = (state: string) => {
  const r = (_.keys(StateIcon) as (keyof typeof StateIcon)[]).find((k) => {
    return k === state;
  });

  // Store the chosen component in a variable starting with Uppercase
  const DynamicIcon = StateIcon[r];

  return <DynamicIcon /> 
};
```